# subprocess.call() to run script from subfolder?

Tags: python, subprocess, subdirectory

I want to run a another sub-script from my current python parent-script which is located in a subfolder of the parent-script with `subprocess.call('sub-script.py',cwd='subfolder')` and it can't find the path. Is there something I am missing on how to use cwd with `subprocess`?

Folders:

```
parent-script.py
---subfolder
   sub-script.py
```

Comment: Difficult to say with so little information, maybe `subproces.call("python sub-script.py".split(),...)`?

Comment: Why would you run Python as a subprocess of Python anyway? There are nearly always better ways to run another script from within yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since `subfolder` is probably not in your path, you need to add "./" when calling sub-script.py (assuming it is executable):

```py
subprocess.call('./sub-script.py', cwd='subfolder')
```

Comment: works equally well when running subprocess.run().